# FindByThumbprint - certificate exists but not found

Tags: c#, azure, ssl-certificate

I am trying to add a certificate to a web request to connect to Azure services.

My code looks like this:

```
string certThumbprint = "‎‎thumbprint";
X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
     X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, certThumbprint, false);
```

Now I can confirm that the certificate does exist and the thumbprint is correct. However `certCollection` comes back empty.

Any ideas?

Update: here is how I open the cert store

```
certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
```

Comment: Which store do you open?

Comment: The Personal/My store

Comment: FYI I can find the certificate by using FindBySubjectName but I would prefer to use FindByThumbprint

Comment: I have seen this failed if the certificate is not valid. Check and verify if certificate is valid. You can create a console app just to try this.

Comment: It is valid from today until 2040

Comment: Most likely you pass the thumbprint in wrong format.

Comment: How are you opening the certificate store?

Comment: @GauravMantri: He's added code for that.

Comment: @sharptooth I was actually looking for X509Store.Open method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store.open.aspx) in the code above. Not sure if `OpenFlags` might have an impact on finding the certificates.

Comment: @GauravMantri: I didn't notice call to `Open()` was missing.

Comment: @sharptooth Yeah. That could very well be the reason for not finding the certificate though andrew-buchan was able to find the certificate by name. Just a thought.

Comment: updated with code to open the cert store

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You probably have a hidden character or two at the very beginning of your thumbprint.  I've made this mistake many times before when copying the thumbprint from the certificate manager in MMC.  Here is a link for more information on this issue.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2023835

Comment: What a pain, character is invisible in VS2013 also!!

Comment: I faced this issue, when you paste the Thumbprint in Skype chat box, you can see the hidden character at the end.

Answer (score 2):

A safe way to get the certificate thumbprints of the Personal Certificates store is to use an elevated instance of PowerShell.

`PS C:\> dir cert:LocalMachine\My | select Thumbprint, FriendlyName, Subject`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue today, while it's possible that there are hidden characters before and after the thumbprint it's also possible that if your debugging runs under a different user, the `StoreLocation.CurrentUser` isn't the same Store as the one you open in Windows.

I had this issue running in Service Fabric on localhost